# Form validation using Bootstrap and AngularJS

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive

I am trying to validate the form using Bootstrap and AngularJS functionality.
Expecting to get the error messages only when the user puts the focus in text field and removes the focus without entering any text. For this I am using `ng-class` directive to perform dynamic class binding but unfortunately it is not working. Don't know what is the issue in code.

**Code:**

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'nameerror': userForm.name.$invalid && userForm.name.$dirty}" >
    <label class="control-label">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" ng-model="user.name" required placeholder="Name" />
    <p ng-show="userForm.name.$invalid && !userForm.name.$pristine" class="help-block">Name is required</p>
</div>
```